# Test suite failed to run ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

i just try testing my app,but i have never done this before, so i have some problem with error "Test suite failed to run ReferenceError: require is not defined" in all my es6 imports. i hear about another way to import but i want try this/

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../App';

test.todo('test');
describe('App', () => {
  it('should render aplication', () => {
    render(<App />);
    const todayButton = screen.getByText(/today/i);
    expect(todayButton).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

it is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.jsx'],
  transform: {
    '\\.[j]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '\\.css$': 'some-css-transformer',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['jsx', 'js', 'json', 'node'],
};
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-calendar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
  },

}
```

Comment: npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-jest

Comment: Create a .babelrc file in the root of your project: and add this - 
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
} 
& restart your server

Comment: i have all your dependecis, and this is my babelrc 
`{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": "> 1%",
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-react", { "runtime": "automatic" }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
`